# String format BigDecimal to show either zero or two decimal places, never one

Tags: java

I'm trying to format some BigDecimals to a currency format.  I need no decimal places to show if there are none in the BigDecimal, but two decimal places to show if there are some (even if it's only 10s)

e.g.

12334    -> 12,334

12334.99 -> 12,334.99

12334.90 -> 12,334.90

not

12334.90 -> 12,334.9

Currently using NumberFormat.getInstance() which fails only for the final example above

Answer (score 1):

```
int precision = val.toString().indexOf('.') != -1 ? 2:0;
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(precision);
String result = formatter.format(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String formatted = formatter.format(number);
if (formatted.endsWith(".00")) {
    formatted = formatted.substring(0, formatted.length()-3);
}
```